# How can I get rid of the text field next to the “Choose file” button in HTML file upload fields, like GMail does?

Tags: html

Hai,
I have one file upload form in an HTML file. The code is like:

```
<form>
Select File:<input type="file">
</form>
```

How can I have only one button (or a link) to upload a file, without having this normal textfield and a browse button? GMail achieves this, but I don’t know how.

Comment: If you only had one button, how would the user see which file they’ve selected to upload? That’s what the “textfield” is for. (It’s not actually a text field, as the user can’t enter arbitrary text into it themselves.)

Comment: How end users will going to choose the file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275990/html-file-upload-field-style

Comment: simply, i would like to have an upload file like gmail.

Comment: @Deepak: aha. When I logged into GMail and right-clicked on their file upload link, the context menu included the item “About Adobe Flash 10.2...”. So it looks like they’re using Flash for that.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: Is there any other option without using flash for acheving this? I simply need a link and when i click i should be able to select a file and that filepath to be shown in a label which was hidden in that form.

Comment: @Deepak: yeah, the two answers below link to some JavaScript only options.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Yahoo User Interface uploader, see http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/

It requires flash on the browser, though.

JQuery UI also has a customized file uploader: http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137894/FileUploader

That's going to involve JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

How about this http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Here is how it goes. First you create a dummy button element or an anchor element. Set its z-index to 1. Place the file upload (`<input type='file' >`) over the aforementioned anchor or button element(dummy) and set opacity filters for the file upload to zero and z-index to be 2. Now it will appear as though ur link or button or image is being clicked. Whereas the file upload layer on top is the one that is being clicked hence you will get your File upload dialog. (Positioning the file upload element can be done with css easily.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the field next to the “Choose file” button, you’ll pretty much have to code your own file upload field using [the JavaScript File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications), or (if you need to cater for [older browsers that don’t support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi)) a browser plug-in like Flash.

Web browsers generally decide how they display HTML form controls. This is actually quite good, as it means the fields look the same on different websites, which means users can be confident that they know what the controls do.

Comment: What about this - https://github.com/ajaxray/bootstrap-file-field ? It's very small in size, just javascript and css (no flash), and ready to use :)

Comment: @Anis: ah yes — I think the new File APIs let you do this in moderns browsers without Flash.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, have a look at this plugin - https://github.com/ajaxray/bootstrap-file-field

This tiny plugin will display the file input field **as a bootstrap button** (no text field), similar in all browser and will show selected file names (or selection errors) beautifully. Check their live demo.

Additionally you can set various restrictions using simple data-attributes or JS settings. e,g, `data-file-types="image/jpeg,image/png"` will restrict selecting file types except jpg and png images.